# powerdns + mongodb

Tags: c++, c, mongodb, compilation, powerdns

I was trying to compile the mongodbbackend module for powerdns but I'm stuck with this problem:

```
In file included from mongodbbackend.cc:18:
mongodbbackend.hh: At global scope:
mongodbbackend.hh:109: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘auto_ptr’ with no type
mongodbbackend.hh:109: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
make[3]: *** [mongodbbackend.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/pdns-3.0.1/modules/mongodbbackend'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/pdns-3.0.1/modules'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/pdns-3.0.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to include files from mongodb 2.0.2 and 2.0.3.
Here are the module sources:
http://wiki.powerdns.com/trac/browser/trunk/pdns/modules/mongodbbackend

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure this is where the errors start? No errors right above it, like "error: client/dbclient.h: No such file or directory" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this patch?

diff --git a/modules/mongodbbackend/mongodbbackend.hh b/modules/mongodbbackend/mongodbbackend.hh
    index 816128f..4f7cf78 100644
    --- a/modules/mongodbbackend/mongodbbackend.hh
    +++ b/modules/mongodbbackend/mongodbbackend.hh
    @@ -1,13 +1,13 @@
     #ifndef MONGODB_HH
     #define MONGODB_HH

```
+#include "client/dbclient.h"
 #include "pdns/dnsbackend.hh"

 #undef VERSION
 #include <string>
 using std::string;
-
-#include "client/dbclient.h"
+using std::auto_ptr;

 class MONGODBException {
 public:
```

It's in https://github.com/azlev/powerdns/commit/a402d8493e5610e139ea19a9ef700e26b2e6e35c

Comment: Hi, it worked! compiled successfully with mongodb 2.0.3
pdns started and successfully connected :) i'll make some test now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The post from Ruben is my anonymous/non-account post. I didn't look at the formatting so the post is a little messed up.

The compiler error you have can be overcome by adding:

`#include<memory>`

And changing line 109 from:

`auto_ptr<mongo::DBClientCursor> cursor;`

to

`std::auto_ptr<mongo::DBClientCursor> cursor;`

This, however, causes other errors on my end (see http://pastebin.com/Wm60JCDu). It might work for you though :-)

It would be helpful if you provide more info about your environment (distro, what version of mangodb and the used mango driver).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, that fixed the problem :) but other issues appeared:
http://pastebin.com/ThRZ4pP1
i'm using debian squeeze with mongodb 2.0.2

Comment: The issues i have are with debian squeeze and the out of the box mongodb.

Comment: From the error you are getting, it seems it has to do with the version of Mongo. I don't know which version of mongodb the author of the mongodbbackend is intending to use. I suggest asking him about that. (see README in the mongodbbackend folder)

Answer (score 1):

The compile error you have can be overcome by adding:

```
#include<memory>
```

and changing

```
auto_ptr<mongo::DBClientCursor> cursor;
```

to

```
std::auto_ptr<mongo::DBClientCursor> cursor;
```

around line *108/109/110* in `mangobackend.hh`

It might work for you, but I think it is heavily depending on the mangodb-api you're using.

It would be helpfull if you provide more info around your environment (distro, version of mango, etc)